# Imprimir div con php wordpress

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código que debería imprimir el div de apertura y de cierre pero no lo hace.

```html
<?php if(has_excerpt()){
  $content = '<div class="except">';
  $content = the_excerpt();
  $content = '</div>';  
  }  
  ?>
```

¿Qué me ha quedado mal?

Gracias

Comment: y donde haces el `echo`?

Comment: Aparte de la falta de `echo` estas reescribiendo la variable `$content` en las tres ocasiones. Tendrías que cambiar las dos ultimas por `$content .= ...`